# Custom Spinner style calendar library like this image android

Tags: android, calendar

Custom font style, color and size with month name not number

[Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIiRR.png)

Answer (score 0):

This could be your solution.
[DateTimePicker](https://github.com/lany192/DateTimePicker)

Sample code is given there.

Comment: It is changing only divider color. I want to change font of Text displayed in DatePicker